# How we know when to stop training a model on a pre-trained model?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, deeplearning4j

My apologies since my question may sound stupid question. But I am quite new in deep learning and caffe.
How can we detect how many iterations are required to fine-tune a pre-trained on our own dataset? For example, I am running fcn32 for my own data with 5 classes. When can I stop the fine-tuning process by looking at the loss and accuracy of training phase?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do it by looking at the loss or accuracy of training phase. Theoretically, the training accuracy should always be increasing (also means the training loss should always be decreasing) because you train the network to decrease the training loss. But a high training accuracy doesn't necessary mean a high test accuracy, that's what we referred as over-fitting problem. So what you need to find is a point where the accuracy of test set (or validation set if you have it) stops increasing. And you can simply do it by specifying a relatively larger number of iteration at first, then monitor the test accuracy or test loss, if the test accuracy stops increasing (or the loss stops decreasing) in consistently N iterations (or epochs), where N could be 10 or other number specified by you, then stop the training process.

Comment: Thanks for very much your comments. I have separated two sets (one train and the other validation). As an instance, I am running FCN32 on my data set with an imbalanced number of classes. the loss and accuracy are fluctuating ` Iteration 58150, loss = 26238.5Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.796127
 Train net output #1: loss = 47338.7 
Iteration 58150, lr = 1e-10
 Iteration 58200, loss = 70063.6
Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.592117
 Train net output #1: loss = 74425.9`.  Is this normal after 58200 iteration? How can I visualize accuracy and loss for TEST phase?

Comment: I never use FCN32 myself. But the loss you post seems wrong, it's too big and increases along with the iteration. So there must be something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you converge to a specific validation accuracy for your model. In practice you normally stop training, if the validation loss did not increase in x epochs. Depending on your epoch duration x may vary most commonly between 5 and 20.

Edit:

An epoch is one iteration over your dataset for trainig in ML terms. You do not seem to have a validation set. Normally the data is split into training and validation data so you can see how well your model performs on unseen data and made decisions about which model to take by looking at this data. You might want to take a look at http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html to see the usage of a validation set, even though they call it test set.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please let me know which one is validation loss and which one is training loss `Iteration 59100, loss = 51478.9
I0116 00:23:45.580317 13755 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.594269
I0116 00:23:45.580333 13755 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #1: loss = 73335.3 (* 1 = 73335.3 loss)` . Both loss and accuracy have a wild fluctuation. BTW, can you please explain what do you mean of epochs? Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is to track training and validation accuracy and store snapshots of the weights every k iterations. To compute validation accuracy you need to have a sparate set of held out data which you do not use for training.
Then, you can stop once the validation accuracy stops increasing or starts decreasing. This is called early stopping in the literature. Keras, for example, provides functionality for this: https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping

Also, it's good practice to plot the above quantities, because it gives you important insights into the training process. See http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#accuracy for a great illustration (not specific to early stopping).

Hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have added a loss layer and accuracy layer for TRAIN phase. The accuracy and loss both are fluctuating. Is there sth wrong with my training? Thanks once again